# Error on Panda3D

Tags: python, panda3d

i am trying to make a screenshot function,
but everytime i try, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\EventManager.py", line 61, in eventLoop
Task
    self.doEvents()
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\EventManager.py", line 55, in doEvents
    processFunc(self.eventQueue.dequeueEvent())
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\EventManager.py", line 122, in processE
vent
    messenger.send(eventName, paramList)
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\Messenger.py", line 397, in send
    self.__dispatch(acceptorDict, event, sentArgs, foundWatch)
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\Messenger.py", line 482, in __dispatch
    method (*(extraArgs + sentArgs))
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 2317, in __oobeButto
n
    messenger.send(button + suffix)
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\Messenger.py", line 397, in send
    self.__dispatch(acceptorDict, event, sentArgs, foundWatch)
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\Messenger.py", line 482, in __dispatch
    method (*(extraArgs + sentArgs))
TypeError: Screenie() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
:task(error): Exception occurred in PythonTask eventManager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Play.py", line 791, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 2921, in run
    self.taskMgr.run()
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\task\Task.py", line 502, in run
    self.step()
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\task\Task.py", line 460, in step
    self.mgr.poll()
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\EventManager.py", line 61, in eventLoop
Task
    self.doEvents()
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\EventManager.py", line 55, in doEvents
    processFunc(self.eventQueue.dequeueEvent())
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\EventManager.py", line 122, in processE
vent
    messenger.send(eventName, paramList)
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\Messenger.py", line 397, in send
    self.__dispatch(acceptorDict, event, sentArgs, foundWatch)
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\Messenger.py", line 482, in __dispatch
    method (*(extraArgs + sentArgs))
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\ShowBase.py", line 2317, in __oobeButto
n
    messenger.send(button + suffix)
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\Messenger.py", line 397, in send
    self.__dispatch(acceptorDict, event, sentArgs, foundWatch)
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.1\direct\showbase\Messenger.py", line 482, in __dispatch
    method (*(extraArgs + sentArgs))
TypeError: Screenie() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Heres the part which does the screenshots

```
def Screenie(self):
file_name = Filename('whatever.png')

self.win.saveScreenshot(file_name)

  base.accept('f9', Screenie)
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong with it? I'm trying to fix it but can't figure out what to do...

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite clear

`TypeError: Screenie() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`

Your `Screenie` function takes one argument (`self`), but whatever is calling it, did so without giving any argument (i.e. `Screenie()` instead of `Screenie(obj)`).

Your choice of `self` as argument to `Screenie` makes me think it is a class method. In that case you should have something like this.

```
class SomeCLass(object):
    # <snip>
    def Screenie(self):
        file_name = Filename('whatever.png')
        self.win.saveScreenshot(file_name)

# Create instance
instance = SomeClass()

# Bind keypress to bound method on instance
base.accept('f9', instance.Screenie)
```

This makes sure that the `self` argument of `Screenie` is bound to the `instance` object, and your code should work.